# Multiple versions of a Windows Store app from a single project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I have an app which is currently available on the Windows and is a paid app. Now I want to create another alternate version of the app and have a free version. I want to be able to change the app name, icon, a few image assets and have conditionals to remove functionality all based on whether I am building the free version or the paid version, all from the same project. In other words I want something similar to creating a new build scheme in Xcode or build flavors/types in Android Studio. I have Google'd and Bing'd for this one and the best thing I can come up with is to branch the project or try making the whole project a library and then creating two other Windows Store projects that simply reference it. Neither of these seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: "Neither of these seems like a good solution to me": why not?

Comment: I believe, the OP question is indeed "(How to create) multiple Windows Store apps from one project". As in, if it's possible to make 2 or more Store packages with different visual assets and slightly different functionality, based on something like project conditional compilation settings.  
Note that the title was changed to a confusing "free-vs-paid" phrasing by a moderator and may cause the question to be closed as "unclear".